# Make tree view for android

Tags: java, android, treeview

I want to make N-Level tree view for my android application, but something goes wrong. I'm not so good in programm development, therefore I ask help here. I use this library https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView

2) Create your tree starting from root element. TreeNode.root() element will not be displayed so it doesn't require anything to be set.

```
TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();
```

Create and add your nodes (use your custom object as constructor param)

```
TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("MyParentNode");
 TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode("ChildNode0");
 TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("ChildNode1");
 parent.addChildren(child0, child1);
 root.addChild(parent);
```

3) Add tree view to layout

```
AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getActivity(), root);
 containerView.addView(tView.getView());
```

The simplest but not styled tree is ready. Now you can see parent node as root of your tree

4) Custom view for nodes

Extend TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder and overwrite createNodeView method to prepare custom view for node:

```
public class MyHolder extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<IconTreeItem> {
    ...
    @Override
    public View createNodeView(TreeNode node, IconTreeItem value) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_profile_node, null, false);
        TextView tvValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.node_value);
        tvValue.setText(value.text);

        return view;
    }
    ...
    public static class IconTreeItem {
        public int icon;
        public String text;
    }
}
```

5) Connect view holder with node

```
IconTreeItem nodeItem = new IconTreeItem();
  TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode(nodeItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(mContext));
```

6) Consider using

```
TreeNode.setClickListener(TreeNodeClickListener listener);
AndroidTreeView.setDefaultViewHolder
AndroidTreeView.setDefaultNodeClickListener
...
```

I have data base with just one table that has fields: ID, PARENT_ID, TYPE, NAME, PRICE_TYPE, ADDRESS. (TYPE holds "1" or "2" 1 - flolder 2 - element).

How to make it correctly? Does anyone can help me with logic how to solv this task? And point out my mistaces.

Comment: Why did you copypaste here the whole 'how-to' section of the library you are using?